# What shall this method return?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table Users , a middle table UserMovies connecting both users and movies, where the relationship is many to many. The user have properties like dateregistered, id, name and movie has 10 other properties. What I am trying to do is just show the name of the user with the movies that he added to Watchlist. 
the logic is fine and it is working , the only problem is what do I need to return in this service?
If I return user I have an error which is I cannot convert IQuerable to Data.Models.User. 
Please help

```
        public User ShowAllMoviesfromWatchlist(string userName)
        {
        var user2 = this.context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == userName); 

        if (user2 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Username '{userName}' does not exist");
        }
        var user = this.context.Users
       .Include(u => u.UserMovie)
        .ThenInclude(um => um.Movie)
         .Select(u => new
         {
             u.Name,
             Movie = u.UserMovie.Select(um => um.Movie.Name).ToList()
         })
         .Where(u => u.Name == userName);
        //  


        var products = user.ToList();

        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Movie);
        }

        //var usermovies = user.UserMovie;
        //return user;
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're expecting this to return a single record:

```
.Where(u => u.Name == userName);
```

Even if there's only one matching record, it's still a collection of records.  The collection simply contains only one.  Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Name == userName);
```

This would return the one matching `User`, or `null` if no users match the query.  (And it would throw an error if there's more than one match.  Which semantically it seems there shouldn't be in this case, so that would be an error you'd want to know about if it happens.)

It's also not entirely clear what you're trying to do in that `.Select()` call.  You might just remove that completely if all you really want is the `User` record and its children.  So ultimately just something like:

```
return context.Users
              .Include(u => u.UserMovie)
              .ThenInclude(um => um.Movie)
              .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Name == userName);
```

Comment: Thank you David for the swift response. I would like to return the user that matches the name and the movies that he has in the watchlist.

Comment: Also If I put .SingleorDefault it will materialize it and I wont be able to return a list of the Movies.

Comment: @grozdeto: Do you want to return a single object or a list of objects?  You need to make up your mind.  What should this method return?  And why is this method writing to the console at all?  What's the goal here?

Comment: I want this method to return a single user with his list of movies. 
I use Select to select which properties I like to return - only the Name of the user and the name of the movie.

Comment: @grozdeto: The code at the end of this answer does exactly that.  It returns a `User` object including its child records.  Don't worry about specifically selecting which columns.  Just return the whole object for simplicity and then only *output* the data you want in the UI.  Otherwise you'll be struggling with either a semi-populated `User` or with an anonymous type.

Comment: thanks David. I can actually manipulate which columns to be shown in the UI even though I have the whole query. I completely forgot about that! Thank you again for your time and help.